# How to replace the last string of a matched word in regex?

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to replace the letter a with EI from all words that has e at the end of the word and then need to remove the last e from the word.
For example:

- `date` will become `deit`
- `cat` will remain `cat`
- `jane` will become `jein`

I have written a regex which replaces a with EI from words that has e at the end but I am not able to remove the last `e`

My regex : `s/a(?=.*e\b)/EI/g`.

Comment: What is the language you are in? Different languages supports different regex features

Comment: @JorgeCampos It looks like Perl to me, but this is a general regex problem, not necessarily dependent on a language.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current regex:

```
s/a(?=.*e\b)/EI/g.
```

Is that the `.*` is *greedy*, and will match across words.  For example, your pattern would target `a` in `banana edible`, because `.*` would detect an `e` in some other word.  Instead, try this find and replace:

**Find:**

```
a(?=[A-Za-z]*e\b)
```

**Replace:**

```
ei
```

Here is a demo showing that the pattern correctly identifies `a` letters for replacement in words ending in `e`:

### Demo

Comment: Thank you Tim but it still does not remove the last e of the word

Comment: yes i wanted sth that will remove the last string...anyways got the answer..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find and replace the following

**Find:**
`([a-zA-Z]*)(a)([a-zA-Z]*)(e\b)`

`([a-zA-Z]*)` ensures zero or more alphabet before first occurrence of `a`

`(a)` ensures `a` is present

`([a-zA-Z]*)` ensures zero or more alphabet before first occurrence of `a`

`(e\b)` ensures word ends with `e`

**Replace:**
`$1ei$3`

`$1` - first capture group

instead of second capture group `(a)` replace with `ei`

`$3` - third capture group

fourth capture group is left out so it removes `e` at the end

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HE1Pga/1)**

Comment: Thanks alot Abdul..works perfectly and this is what I wanted .can you please explain the logic you used? :)

Comment: @Safa added explanation of the regex